# how can I print membes of this structure pointed by a tree node void pointer?

Tags: c, printing, void

```
typedef struct{
     int codigo;     
     char *nome;  

} Un_curricular;

typedef struct tnode{
    struct tnode *left;
    struct tnode *right;
    void *data;
} Tnode;

typedef struct{
    Tnode *root;
    int (*compare)(void *data1, void *data2 );
} Tree;

int main(void){

    Tree *tree = malloc(sizeof(Tree) );
    tree->compare = NULL;

    Tnode *t = malloc(sizeof( Tnode) );
    t->right = NULL;
    t->left = NULL;

    Un_curricular * uc = malloc(sizeof(Un_curricular) );
    uc->nome = "PGII";
    uc->codigo = 10;

    t->data = uc; 

    tree->root = t;

    printf("%s\n",tree->root->data->nome);

}
```

Having only the pointer to tree, how can I print codigo and *nome on stdout
I've tried:

tree->root->data->nome
and
tree->root->data-codigo

but it doesn't work.

main.c: In function ‘main’:

main.c:39: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer

main.c:39: error: request for member ‘nome’ in something not a structure or union

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to derefence a `void*` pointer, but it's size isn't known from your compiler. That's why you get this error.
If you want to print a part of an `Un_curricular*` you have to make an explicit cast in a `Un_curricular*` variable.

```
Un_curricular* u = (Un_curricular*) tree->root->data;
printf("%s\n", u->nome);
```

Comment: it worked!thank you so much, been with this for hours.